# ActiveRecord still save parent object if validations on children fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

With a relationship setup like:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
  validates_presence_of :first_name
end

p = Parent.new
p.children.build

p.save
=> false

p.errors
=> {:children => ["is invalid"]}
```

Is there a way to keep the validations on the child object, but not have their failed validation block the save of the parent?

Comment: This addresses the question I was about to ask - I had no idea that this was the default behaviour (i.e. invalid children blocking parent) - are you able to confirm that is the case? TY

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `save(options={})` in `ActiveRecord::Validations`.

You can pass in `:validate => false` to save(), which will skip the call to `valid?`.

This will also skip any validations on the parent object, so you may have to do something more involved if the parent has validations as well.

[Source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's not rails style, but it answers your question. So just manage association by yourself:

```
p = Parent.new
p.save
c = Children.new(:parent_id => p.id)
c.save => 'first name can't be blank"
```